# All relationships are not created in neo4j

Tags: csv, neo4j, nodes

i am new to neo4j and i am facing a rare problem that after creating 4359 nodes of different customerID and 3676 nodes of different ProductID s  and when creating relationships between them for all the ProductIDs i have created there are less relationships created for that product id. Suppose in CSV file i have 479 columns for that particular productID but when checking the count of incoming edges the result is 477. this is happening for all the ProductID s

thanks in advance

Comment: please share your code... do you use `MERGE` ? Is there a possibility there are two duplicates in your data ?

Comment: first i created all unique customerIDs and then unique ProductIDs and then the relation. I have three CSV files one is having unique CustomerIDs and Other Unique ProductIDs and the third  actual CSV with all the data i have some 404666 records. So when creating relationships i tried both merge and create. In both the cases  same result

Comment: are you using `MATCH` in the last csv import ?

Comment: yes, first i match the nodes and then i create relationship between matched nodes. while creating relationship i tried both merge and create

Comment: so the problem is usually here that two `MATCH` statements do not find what they were looking for, hence two less relations... try to `MATCH` only and return count(*) to see if this is the case